# Solution properties of $au''(t) + bu'(t) + u(t) = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $au''(t) + bu'(t) + u(t) = 0 $.

Find the values of $a$ and $b$ so that the above ODE has a solution $u$ that:

1. $|u| \rightarrow \infty$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$
2. $u$ is perodic
3. $u \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$

Is there a way to determine this WITHOUT actually solving the ODE?

Comment: Is there a way to find the solution *without solving?!*

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: I am not interested in the solution itself, just the values of $a$ and $b$ that makes it have a certain property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to solve the ode by assuming the solution as $y=e^{mt}$ then plugging back in the ode and solving the resulting polynomial in $m$. Once you consruct the general solution, you can see what conditions you need to impose on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @BabakS.: Thanks for the comment.